# Change background for cell in Calendar using Python Tkinter?

Tags: python, windows, tkinter, calendar, tkcalendar

I want to change the background for a particular cell in this calendar

```
cal = Calendar(root,selectmode="day",year=2020,month=7,day=10)
```

in Tkinter.
but I do not know how to do that
please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can attach a tag to the particular day using `calevent_create()` and then use `tag_config()` to change the background color using the tag:

Below is an example:

```py
import datetime

...

day = datetime.date(2020, 7, 20)
cal.calevent_create(day, "", tags="hi")
cal.tag_config("hi", background="red")
```